# How to display high resolution picture of the decision tree in Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, decision-tree

Am using the following code to extract rules. Please help me plot a tree of higher resolution as the image gets blurred when I increase the tree depth.

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn import tree
classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth = 3,random_state = 0)
tree.plot_tree(classifier);
```

Also, how can I extract rule from a random Forest Classifier.

Also are there

Comment: note that this is just a tree, not a forest.  maybe post another question that covers that?  note that normally you'd not want to "extract" any "rule" from it, just use the classifier directly.  each tree consists of many rules and a forest consists of many trees and hence (many rules)**2, this quickly gets awkward

Comment: Please focus your posts to one question at the time and resist the "*also...*" temptation, unless you have more that one very *related* questions; here, how to plot a single decision tree and how to get the rules from an RF are completely different questions and they should not be asked in a single post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd just save the plot to a PDF file and use that to zoom in to whichever part you want

just put `plt.savefig('out.pdf')` after your call to `plot_tree` and matplotlib should do the right thing

note that any "vector" image format will do the right thing here, so a `svg` file would also be a fine choice as image editors tend to support zooming more nicelyer